# How to display table values to listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

How do I display a table value in a listbox control? From this code I got the **ProjectCode** value from the TeamMember_table:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select ProjectCode from TeamMember_table where EmpId = '" + eid + "'", conn);
```

I want to display this **ProjectCode** value in a **listBox**.

Platform: Visual Studio 2008, ASP.NET with C#.

Answer (score 2):

Using the ASP.NET ListBox control you can do it by assigning the DataSource property:

```
 ListBox1.DataSource = YourDataSource;
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "projectCode";
        ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Where "YourDataSource" can be a DataTable filled with data from your SqlDataAdapter.

You can also add every item manually:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
            item.Text="sometext";
            item.Value="somevalue";
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

You can read more about data binding and the ASP.NET ListBox control [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx).